# How to adjust font-size of paragraph to fill the item height inside a flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-size

I'm creating a flexbox container with several items that contain text but not all texts have same lenght. I want to resize automatically the font size of text for fill the height of every flexbox item.

I have tried to set font-size with vh and another units and tried the js plugin FitText but it make all texts bigger.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:space-between">
   <blockquote  class="articulo">
       <p>Aprendizaje y práctica de la conciencia plena en estudiantes de bachillerato para potenciar la relajación y la autoeficacia en el rendimiento escolar</p>
       <small><cite">universitas psychologica</cite></small>
   </blockquote>
   <blockquote  class="articulo">
       <p>Prevalencia de la depresión en España: Análisis de los últimos 15 años.</p>
       <small><cite">universitas psychologica</cite></small>
   </blockquote>
   <blockquote  class="articulo">
       <p>Instrumentos para la evaluación de la sobrecarga del cuidador familiar de personas con demencia.</p>
       <small><cite>universitas psychologica</cite></small>
   </blockquote>
   <blockquote  class="articulo">
       <p>Impulsividad y consumo de alcohol y tabaco en adolescentes.</p>      
       <small><cite>universitas psychologica</cite></small>
   </blockquote>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.articulo{
    width:30%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-left:3px solid #92c500;
}

.articulo cite{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

This is what I have:

[image: what I have]

and something like this is what I want:

[image: what I want]

Answer (score 0):

This post gives quite a few answers, in terms of plugins and others:
[Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

you'll have to make sure whatever you apply changes font size in regards to height and not width!

And I think using SVG as shown by [Danto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5025024/danto) like this would work for your case:

```
<div style="height: 60px;">  
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -200 1000 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text font-size="300" fill="black">Text</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about set font size 16px as  default then  use JavaScript or jquery and get the text length ,then check if length is < (num),set 18px font for example!

Comment: But I want something that fit the height without set an specific size. (If exists)